# Nested class inside static block not identified by outer class's method

Tags: java, class, static, nested

This is my code:

```
class Outer
{
    static int x=10;
    static
    { 
        class Inner
        {
           void disp()
           {
               System.out.println(x);
           }
        }
    }
    void outdisp()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Inner in = new Inner();
            in.disp();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Outer out = new Outer();
        out.outdisp();
    }
}
```

I just want to know why the method `outdisp()` doesn't identify the *class* `Inner` in this case, while it works fine if I declare the `Inner` class as static instead of in a static block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of any identifier is within surrounding `{...}`, here it is static initializer `static{...}`. So identifier `Inner` is just not visible in the method `outdisp()`.

Move declaration of class `Inner` outside the static initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any *static inner class* there. You're confusing with *static block*. A *static inner class* would be written as follows:

```
static class Inner { ... }
```

It doesn't work because the [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) will be executed when the JVM loads `Outer` class.

Remove the keyword `static` and you'll be fine.